# Where am I messing up with output formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format, string-formatting

So I got an error message when I tried to run my code and I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. It says it's a ValueError but I can't figure out which one exactly. Maybe it's just late, but I am at a loss.

Here's my code:

```
def sort(count_dict, avg_scores_dict, std_dev_dict):
    '''sorts and prints the output'''
    menu = menu_validate("You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 \n        Sort Options\n    1. Sort by Avg Ascending\n    2. Sort by Avg Descending\n    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending\n    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending", 1, 4)
    print ("{}{0:27}{0:39}{0:51}\n{}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))

    if menu == 1:       
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 2:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_average_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 3:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 4:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{}{0:27}{0:39:.4f}{0:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))

    return None
```

Here's my output and error when I run it:

```
You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 
        Sort Options
    1. Sort by Avg Ascending
    2. Sort by Avg Descending
    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending
    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Program 7\Program 7.py", line 161, in <module>
    output = sort(cnt_dict, word_avg_dict, std_dev_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Program 7\Program 7.py", line 99, in sort
    print ("{}{0:27}{0:39}{0:51}\n{}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

What am I messing up? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch back and forth between automatic field numbering - what you get by specifying a simple `{}` - and manual field specification, e.g. `{0}`. If you want the same field repeated several times, as `'Word'` is in your example, you'll have to also specify what you want the other fields to be. For example, you might want to start with the first argument, `'Word'`, which is element `0`, and the fifth argument, `'='*51`, as the last, which is element `4`:

```
>>> print("{0}{0:27}{0:39}{0:51}\n{4}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))
WordWord                       Word                                   Word

===================================================
```

You'll have to decide for yourself which arguments you want to be placed where in the format string.