# Where am I screwing up with my output formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, string-formatting

So I got an error message when I tried to run my code (continued from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831827/where-am-i-messing-up-with-output-formatting)) and I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. It says it's a ValueError but I can't figure out which one exactly. Maybe it's just late, but I am at a loss.

Here's my code:

```
def sort(count_dict, avg_scores_dict, std_dev_dict):
    '''sorts and prints the output'''
    menu = menu_validate("You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 \n        Sort Options\n    1. Sort by Avg Ascending\n    2. Sort by Avg Descending\n    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending\n    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending", 1, 4)
    print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39}{3:51}\n{4}".format("Word", "Occurence", "Avg. Score", "Std. Dev.", "="*51))

    if menu == 1:       
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_avg_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39:.4f}{3:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 2:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(word_avg_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39:.4f}{3:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 3:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=False))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39:.4f}{3:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
    elif menu == 4:
        dic = OrderedDict(sorted(std_dev_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
        for key in dic:
            print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39:.4f}{3:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))

    return None
```

Here's my output and error when I run it:

```
You must choose one of the valid choices of 1, 2, 3, 4 
        Sort Options
    1. Sort by Avg Ascending
    2. Sort by Avg Descending
    3. Sort by Std Deviation Ascending
    4. Sort by Std Deviation Descending1
WordOccurence                  Avg. Score                             Std. Dev.                                          
===================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Program 7\Program 7.py", line 161, in <module>
    output = sort(cnt_dict, word_avg_dict, std_dev_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Program 7\Program 7.py", line 104, in sort
    print ("{0}{1:27}{2:39:.4f}{3:51:.4f}".format(key, count_dict[key], avg_scores_dict[key], std_dev_dict[key]))
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

What am I messing up? Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: not a duplicate. new ValueError, updated code

Comment: Could have updated the last question with these changes.

Comment: @AKS - It is a different problem with a different solution, not a repeat of the other question. Updating the original question with new tasks would make it less useful with each successive change. However, it would be good to add a link to that question in this one.

Comment: What are you trying to do by putting two colons in your format specifiers?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have multiple colons in a single specification field, like `{3:51:.4f}`. Remove the second one:

```
>>> print("{0}{1:27}{2:39.4f}{3:51.4f}".format('a', 'b', 1.234567, 9.876543))
ab                                                           1.2346                                             9.8765
```